# Adding a column in a SQL VIEW with a different GROUP by clause?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Age|Account_Number
1  |101  
1  |101
1  |102   
2  |102
2  |102
3  |101    
3  |102   
4  |101 
4  |101 
5  |102     
5  |102     
5  |102
5  |101
```

So far I created a VIEW like so:

```
Create VIEW view1 as
SELECT age, count(Account_Number) as totalAttempts
GROUP by Age
```

My goal is to have a view table that looks like this:

```
Age  | totalAttempts  | 1attempt   | 2attempt | 3attempt | 
1    |3               |1           |2         |0         |
2    |2               |0           |2         |0         |
3    |2               |2           |0         |0         |
4    |2               |0           |2         |0         |
5    |4               |1           |0         |3         |
```

The addition of 1attempt + 2attempt + 3attempt = totalAttempts.  Basically these new columns that I want to add is dependent on the Account_Number and how many times they appear per line in the table. If the value 102 in Account_number appears once in the table but only in Age 1, then 1attempt = 1.  If the value 101 in Account_number appears twice in the table but only in Age 1, then 2attempt = 2.  How would I add these columns to the view?

Comment: I don't understand your explanation. What is the 3attempt? please explain about Age=3 and explain why you have those numbers in attempt fields.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the misconfusion. Numbers in the xattempt column(in this case lets reference 3attempt) represents how many times an Account_number shows up only in Age=3, in this case its 0 so 3attempt = 0. Since Account_number 101 and 103 only showed up once per line in Age=3 then BOTH these values are added to a counter and added to 1attempt.  One thing to note is that if we look at Age=5 , 3attempt=3 because 102 shows up 3 times

Comment: By reviewing more and more on sample data, I understood the logic, however your explanation still is not clear. I try to find the query

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I also included test data creation to be able to test

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE #test

CREATE TABLE #test (Age int, account varchar(5))
INSERT INTO #test VALUES 
(1, '101'),  (1, '101'), (1, '102'), (2, '102'), (2, '102'), 
(3, '101'), (3, '102'), (4, '101'), (4, '101'), 
(5, '102'), (5, '102'), (5, '102'), (5, '101')

;WITH tot AS (
  SELECT Age, account, count(*) cnt
  FROM #test 
  GROUP BY Age, account
)
, at1 AS (
  SELECT * FROM tot
  WHERE cnt = 1
)
, at2 AS (
  SELECT * FROM tot
  WHERE cnt = 2
)
, at3 AS (
  SELECT * FROM tot
  WHERE cnt = 3
)
, final AS (
  SELECT tot.Age, tot.cnt
    , at1.cnt AS attempt_1, at2.cnt AS attempt_2, at3.cnt AS attempt_3
  FROM tot 
    Full JOIN at1 ON at1.Age = tot.Age AND at1.account = tot.account
    Full JOIN at2 ON at2.Age = tot.Age AND at2.account = tot.account
    Full JOIN at3 ON at3.Age = tot.Age AND at3.account = tot.account
)
SELECT Age, sum(cnt) TotalAttempts
 , sum(isnull(attempt_1, 0)) Attempt_1, sum(isnull(attempt_2, 0)) Attempt_2
, sum(isnull(attempt_3, 0)) Attempt_3
FROM final 
GROUP BY Age
ORDER BY Age
```

This would be the result

```
Age TotalAttempts   Attempt_1   Attempt_2   Attempt_3
1       3               1           2           0
2       2               0           2           0
3       2               2           0           0
4       2               0           2           0
5       4               1           0           3
```

Comment: Thanks. Whenever someone gives you an answer, you should give him a credit by marking the post as answer.